# How to update a chosen variable in a list in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a bunch of variables (of same shape) among which I have to choose **one** to update depending on the value of `self.action_holder`. So I stored these variables in a **list** `self.weights`. Here is my updating rule

`self.update = optimizer.minimize(self.loss, var_list = [tf.gather(self.weights, self.action_holder)])`.

This will cause error

`No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph for ops that do not support gradients, between variables ['Tensor("GatherV2:0", shape=(2, 10, 10), dtype=float32)'] and loss Tensor("mul:0", dtype=float32).`

But if I change my updating code to this

`self.update = optimizer.minimize(self.loss, var_list = [self.weights[0]])`.

No error will be thrown. However I'm updating the first weight in `self.weights` all the time, which is not the updation I want here.

I'm quite confused here. Isn't that true `tf.gather(list, index)` = `list[index]` in Tensorflow? Why it not work here? Am I missing something?

Comment: Or is there a way to selectively update a variable in Tensorflow? Like selectively update a weight in a bilinear model?

Comment: I actually tried to select variables by their names but I cannot get over the Tensor dtype is not int thing...